# Getting exception when upgrading to workbox version 5: "workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute is not a function"

Tags: workbox

I am trying to upgrade to verison 5 of workbox, and I am getting an exception on a line of code that previously worked fine:

```
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute is not a function
```

I have a SPA built on Blazor framework, and the offending line of code is:

```
//SPA fallback for navigation requests
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html');
```

I am not using a bundler and using plain javascript, and I am finding to difficult to understand the current docs, as they all assume usage of a module bundler.

Answer (score 0):

In workbox 5 the function name is `registerRoute`.

You can check the [Common Recipes](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes) and these migration guides for more info/help:

- [Migrate from sw-precache or sw-toolbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw)
- [Migrate from Workbox v2 to v3](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v2)
- [Migrate from Workbox v3 to v4](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v3)
- [Migrate from Workbox v4 to v5](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v4)

Comment: Here is the guide to [Migrate from Workbox v5 to v6](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-v5)